Shell extension in Explorer run as administrator
I have a shell extension(COM server in a dll adding a new menu item in the context menu) that runs well in Explorer run as a normal user. I want to see if it can run in Explorer run as administrator, so I right-click C:\windows\explorer.exe and select "run as administrator". Then I find the shell extension is not started in the Explorer run as administrator. Then, I enable the administrator account in Windows 10 and login the PC as administrator, and find the shell extension works well there. However, when I switch back to the normal account, the shell extension is neither started in normal explorer nor the explorer run as administrator until I restart explorer.
What are the possible reasons?

Because explorer doesn't run as administrator when you right click on it and select run as administrator https://superuser.com/questions/1373691/how-can-i-truly-run-windows-file-explorer-with-full-administrator-privileges-on

@Really? I'm not aware of this fact. Thanks for the information. But even the explorer is not run as administrator, the shell extension should run in the new explorer process, why did not it happen? Is it related to the ThreadingModel? The ThreadingModel of the inprocserver is set to Apartment.

By default you shouldn't have a new explorer.exe, running explorer even as admin will use the already started one, but one can configure lots of things in Windows (like tweaking UAC, running on Windows Server, etc.) so I can't say, also it depends if you register the COM object in HKCU or in HKLM etc. In any case, the threading model has nothing to do with this. You should share a fully reproducing code and test case
